# Create a socket to listen for data in xamarin, android

Tags: c#, android, sockets, xamarin

The following code is code I've use in a windows program many times with no problem.

```
rec_Socket.Connect(m_EPhost);
Form1 state = new Form1();
state.workSocket = rec_Socket;
rec_Socket.BeginReceive(m_RecvBytes, 0, m_RecvBytes.Length, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
```

What changes do I need to make to make this code work for an android Xamarin application.  Obviously I get an error for Form1 which would not be in an android application. I also show an error for "workSocket" in the 3rd line.

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting?  Are we supposed to guess?  Please include the relevant portions of the code and any error messages or exceptions.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: For "Form1" it says, "The type or namespace name "Form1" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: For "workSocket" it says "Undeclared element" I believe because it doesn't like "Form1".

Comment: I assume that Form1 is of type System.Windows.Forms. You can check that on your other programs. Xamarin does not support the entire System.Windows namespace because it is not relevant for mobile development. In fact it is entirely bound to Windows UI development.

The "Undeclared element" message is a follow up because - as you mentioned already - it does not know the type.

Comment: Yes, I know that. The question was what can I replace the "Form1" object with in a mobile app to make my socket code work.